# How to switch to iframe if it is dynamically created using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

In my case iframes are dynamically created while loading,sometimes 2 sometimes 3 iframes are created. I want to get the last iframe.I tried

```
  iframe_list =  driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")
  length = len(iframe_list)
  print(length) 
  length=length-1 // because switch_to.frame starts with 0
  print(length)
  driver.switch_to.frame(length) // not working
```

using this i couldn't access the elements inside this iframes and i tried to print also

```
  print(driver.switch_to.frame(length))  // output None
```

[image]
so how to get last iframe when its dynamically creates using python selenium

Comment: Please post your relevant html or url?

Comment: Sorry it's my company private url..I think in question itself i clearly mention that each time loading the iframes are created dynamically like 2,3 etc... i want to switch into last iframe. How it can be implement? @Kunduk

Comment: Is this nested `iframe`? can you post an image to confirm whether it is nested iframe?

Answer (score 0):

To get the last iframe element.

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")[-1])
```

Or use [last()] with xpath.

```
 driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//iframe)[last()]"))
```

Comment: it's not a nested iframe ... attached screenshot

Comment: @DivyaMani : Check my updated answer.Let me know how this goes?